# WSO2 API manager : display bug

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When you activate the "Go to APIStore" link from publisher (in api-manager.xml), it displays "Go to Go to APIStore".

How to correct this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to  : repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/site/themes/wso2/templates/page/base/template.jag and correct the line 92 :

```
Go to <%=i18n.localize(“Go to APIStore”)%>
```